# Write $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}} - \frac{1}{2}$ with a rational denominator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}} - \frac{1}{2}$ with a rational denominator.

How should I solve this question?

Comment: First : imagine the denominator of the first fraction was $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$. Could you do it then? Basically, you need to rationalize, twice.

Comment: Yes. Rationalise the first term (the one containing all those irrationals - not $ \frac{1}{2}$!)

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator in the first term by $(\sqrt 6) (\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)$ and see what you get.

Comment: Ok, I rationalized the first term, so should I just put that back with $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ and I'm done?

Comment: @infinity Yep, I think so. Post what you got as an answer, so we can verify that as well!

Comment: Rationalize it twice. For the first rationalization group two irrationals together

Comment: I got $\dfrac{3+\sqrt6+\sqrt15}{6}$ by rationalizing the first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Only the first term

We have $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 5}.$ Do :
$$
\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 5}= \frac{\sqrt 2(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3  + \sqrt 5)}{(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)^2 - 5} = \frac{2 + \sqrt 6 + \sqrt {10}}{2\sqrt 6} \\
= \frac{2\sqrt 6 + 6 + \sqrt {60}}{2\sqrt 6 \sqrt 6} = \frac{6 + 2 \sqrt 6 + \sqrt {60}}{12}= \frac{3+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt {15}}{6}
$$

So you are correct!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!